# Can BufferedReader (Java) read next line without moving the pointer?

Tags: java

I am trying to read next next line without moving the pointer, is that possible?

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));

while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {
}
```

the While will read line by line as i want, but i need to write the next line of the current line.

it is possible?

my file contain Http request data, the first line is the GET request,
in the second line the Host name, i need to pull out the Host before the GET to be able to connect it together.
Host/+the GET url,

```
GET /logos/2011/family10-hp.jpg HTTP/1.1  
Host: www.google.com  
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `mark()` and `reset()` to mark a spot in the stream and then return to it.  Example:

```
int BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

buf.mark(BUFFER_SIZE);
buf.readLine();  // returns the GET
buf.readLine();  // returns the Host header
buf.reset();     // rewinds the stream back to the mark
buf.readLine();  // returns the GET again
```

Comment: perfect solution!! It solve my read file problem where I had to do some logic on the next line, then go back to the previous one to set the condition.

Answer (score 19):

Just read both current and next line in the loop.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file, encoding));
    for (String next, line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = next) {
        next = reader.readLine();

        System.out.println("Current line: " + line);
        System.out.println("Next line: " + next);
    }
} finally {
    if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Balus!  Don't think it was just eclipse - but I did have to modify the "for" line of code to be `for (String next = "", line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = next) {` to get rid of of a compiler problem of "The local variable next may not have been initialized"