# java BufferedReader roll back to previous line

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm reading text from a file using BufferedReader, when some condition evaluates to true I want to roll back to the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your reader in a [PushbackReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html).

From the javadoc:

> A character-stream reader that allows characters to be pushed back
>   into the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Use [java.io.RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to parse the file then, buffered reader is meant to read the file sequentially.

Using `java.io.RandomAccessFile` you can read file as

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("c:\\data\\file.txt", "rw");
file.seek(200);
long pointer = file.getFilePointer();
file.close()
```

To read or write at a specific location in a RandomAccessFile you must first position the file pointer at the location to read or write. This is done using the seek() method. The current position of the file pointer can be obtained by calling the getFilePointer() method.

[Reference](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/randomaccessfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mark()` method  provided by the `BufferedReader` class and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901508/can-bufferedreader-java-read-next-line-without-moving-the-pointer) you can get example.
You can use `FileUtils` in apache commons which will be more easier [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Example:

```
String line = FileUtils.readLines(aFile).get(lineNumber);
```

You can achieve your requirement using this.

Note:  apache commons-io.jar file should be in the classpath, You can download [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi)