# Problem reading file in Java with lines of different length

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a file but I am not able to get the correct output from it. Can someone tell me how should I change the code to make it work? isNum() function in the code is a method that checks whether the string is a number or not (because I need to put 5 and 10 in a separate variable).

Edit: I have changed the code a bit after listening to the suggestions and it looks better now but there still some problem. The code and output below has been updated.

```
        int numEv = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> evtList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            input = new Scanner(Paths.get("src/idse/Events.txt"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        try {
            
            while(input.hasNext()) {
                String a = input.nextLine();
                
                if (isNum(a)){
                    numEv = Integer.parseInt(a);
                    System.out.println(numEv);
                }
                else if(!a.isEmpty()&&!isNum(a)){
                    String[] parts = a.split(":");
                    for (String part : parts) {
                        evtList.add(part);
                    }
                    System.out.println(evtList);
                }
                if(isNum(a)){
                    evtList.clear();
                }
                
            }
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
5
[Logins, 2, Total time online, 1, Emails sent, 1, Orders processed, 1]
[Logins, 2, Total time online, 1, Emails sent, 1, Orders processed, 1, Pizza’s ordered online, 0.5]
10
[Logins, 7, Total time online, 5, Emails sent, 9, Orders processed, 15]
[Logins, 7, Total time online, 5, Emails sent, 9, Orders processed, 15, Pizza’s ordered online, 0.9, Logouts, 6]
```

The output that I want is:

```
5
[Logins, 2, Total time online, 1, Emails sent, 1, Orders processed, 1, Pizza’s ordered online, 0.5]
10
[Logins, 7, Total time online, 5, Emails sent, 9, Orders processed, 15, Pizza’s ordered online, 0.9, Logouts, 6]
```

Comment: 1. You never clear your arraylist 2. Is the input file supposed to have a new line between lines 2 and 3 and between lines 5 and 6?

Comment: 1. Yeah I tried clearing the arraylist but that doesn't produce the desired output either.  2. Yeah the input file is supposed to be like this.

Comment: Then I would recommend either 1. always make the last `:` of your input code `::`. This way you know where the input code ends OR 2. Only print your array in the first `if` and then clear the array

Comment: I can't change the format of the input file, I have to code according to the specifications I was given.

Comment: The problem is you do not know where the input code ends (_Logins:2:Total time online:1:_). If it was only a single line, you would know it ends at the line it starts - easy. But with it stretching over multiple lines you have no real clue where the code ends.

Comment: Then I think your best choice is option 2

Comment: @CodingTil I am trying to check if the nextLine has a number or not to check if the input with delimiters has ended or not. Shouldn't it be possible this way?

Comment: Oh yeah thats similar, but better

Comment: Dont forget to also check if it is the end of the file!

Comment: @CodingTil I have updated the code, can you see if there's anything else I can do to get the correct output? The code is still printing two arraylists and the one at the bottom is the only one I want.

Comment: 1. Your second `isNum()` check does the same as your first. You never update your `a` (thought you wanted to get the next line?). Don't forget then to go back to the last line
2. Print your arraylist in the second `isNum()` if statement

Comment: @CodingTil `a` is updated everytime the while loop runs and the result I get when I print the arraylist in the second isNum() is still incorrect (and worse).

Comment: @CodingTil what would be the correct value of mark be in the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224356/discussion-between-miztory-and-codingtil).

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 fixes you should do, follow the next steps:

1. Correct your file format.
   change the format to:

```
5
Logins:2:Total time online:1:Emails sent:1:Orders processed:1:Pizza’s ordered online:0.5:
10
Logins:7:Total time online:5:Emails sent:9:Orders processed:15:Pizza’s ordered online:0.9:Logouts:6:
```

Thud will sperate the file by lines as you want.

2. Enter the `System.out.println()` method to the code blocks:

```
if (isNum(a)){
      numEv = Integer.parseInt(a);
      System.out.println(numEv);
}
else if(!a.isEmpty()&&!isNum(a)){
     String[] parts = a.split(":");
     for (String part : parts) {
          evtList.add(part);
     }
     System.out.println(evtList);
}
```

This will fix you too long output, because its prints some unneccery stuff.

3. Clear the event list:

```
evtList.clear();
```

Add this line after every iteration in the while loop, to make list update **only** to the current line, and not full of nodes from previous events.

Comment: I have updated the code and output above, can you see if there's anything else I can do to get the correct output? The code is still printing two arraylists and the one at the bottom is the only one I want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you specified in the comments (e.g. You cannot change the input file format), you would always have to check the next line of the file to see if the specific input code has ended. I would use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901508/can-bufferedreader-java-read-next-line-without-moving-the-pointer) to read the next line without moving the pointer.

```
int numEv = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // idk what you need this for
ArrayList<String> evtList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Paths.get("src/idse/Events.txt")));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

try {
        
    while((a= reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (isNum(a)){ // Reading and printing the number
            numEv = Integer.parseInt(a);
            System.out.println(numEv);
        } else if(!a.isEmpty()){ // Getting and storing the code
            String[] parts = a.split(":");
            for (String part : parts) {
                evtList.add(part);
            }
        }
        reader.mark(0);
        a = reader.readLine();
        if(a == null || isNum(a)) { // If the next line is a number or doesn't exist, we print and clear the code
            System.out.println(evtList);
            evtList.clear();
        }
        reader.reset();
    }
```

I hope this works!

Comment: I fixed the errors in the code and it reads part of the file correctly but then it throws an exception `5
[Logins, 2, Total time online, 1, Emails sent, 1, Orders processed, 1, Pizza’s ordered online, 0.5]
10
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mark invalid` Do you know what the issue might be? The first arraylist is correct though.